# Does Kale super saiyajin green transformation have a name?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Kale aka "female Broly" (unofficial nickname) is shown to have a super saiyan transformation of green color similar in aspect to the transformation of Broly. Does this transformation already have an official name? (from japanese magazines, previews, etc.?)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don' t think so. DBS is making a really long list of these unexplained new transformations..

Comment: Nothing has been confirmed yet, within the next few episodes we should have our answer though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the transformation name is going to be "**Super Saiyan Berserk**" because some Dragon Ball Super figurines (toys) of Kale transformed in SSJ appeared, and they are labeled like that. Besides a provisional title for DBS episode 100 appeared, and it is (spoiler)

> Awakening of the Berserk Warrior!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lGKrSJOqlk

Update: 16/07/2017 In the preview of Dragon Ball Super episode 100, the title is "Out of control. The savage Berserker awakens!!" so I guess we can take this as her confirmed name.

Comment: Do you have any sources to point out for these toys?

Comment: The youtube video mentions the toys and the name refered in the post. The toys can be seen here (with the same name) https://www.reddit.com/r/dbz/comments/6dh9pj/dragon_ball_super_new_toys_including_jiren_and/ not sure if I can upload that photo because it has a watermark

Comment: Ah, I was under the presumption that the video was just a clip showing the preview for episode 100.

Answer (score 0):

Legendary Super Saiyan or Super Saiyan Berserk.
I think they call it Super saiyan Berserk because in the Dragon Ball series, Goku and CO never meet Broly, so they have no idea about the green transformation. So they refer to the way Kale act when transformed.